# Parse JavaScript QML item to C++ QT

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

I have a JavaScript function in QML which creates and returns a component (`Item`):

```
function addMyComponent() {
    var component = Qt.createComponent('MyComponent.qml');
    var obj = component.createObject(container, {'x': 0, 'y': 0});
    return obj; // Not sure weather to return obj or component for my C++ to use
}
```

I also have some QML in `main.qml` which is using a custom C++ class I have made:

```
// ...
import com.acidic.customclass 1.0
import "AddMyComponent.js" as AddMyComponent

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 800

    CustomClass {
        id: customClass
    }

    Button {
        onClicked: {
            customClass.receiveComponent(AddMyComponent.addMyComponent)
        }
    }
}
```

And my C++ class header:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void receiveComponent(const QObject& obj /* QObject ref doesn't work */);
```

and body:

```
void CustomClass::receiveComponent(const QObject& obj) {
    qDebug(obj.property("width")); // To see if we have received it correctly
}
```

---

How can I parse a component created with JavaScript and `Qt.createComponent` into my custom C++ class' function parameter?

Comment: You should use `Q_INVOKABLE void receiveComponent(QObject* pObj);`.

Comment: @AlexanderVX that worked! Thank you, I'd be willing to accept it as an answer if you post it

Comment: I just don't understand why this is downvoted!!!

Comment: @MohammadKanan Idk too !! :(

Comment: @Acidic Just cannot remember the proper link to docs but there few. I posted "Data Type Conversion Between QML and C++" link with the answer. At least that is some clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have QML UI objects derived from `QQuickItem` (for Qt Quick) which is `QObject` and other 'auxiliary' objects also used in QML derived from `QObject` base:

```
// QObject pointer should work with QML objects
Q_INVOKABLE void receiveComponent(QObject* pObj);
```

Mind that there also `QString`, `QVariant`, `QVariantList`, `QVariantMap` and other Qt primitives. For the [reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html).

Comment: Also, I would recommend @Acidic tries `Q_INVOKABLE void receiveComponent(QQuickItem* pQuickItem);` as the initializer varlist tells me that it's likely a `QQuickItem`.  The more specific the typing, the better the runtime performance / readability, as a general rule.